# Monkey-patch using modules in a gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I'm building a Ruby gem that includes a module that's meant to monkey-patch the Hash class to add a new method. I'm following this guide to try to do it neatly: http://www.justinweiss.com/articles/3-ways-to-monkey-patch-without-making-a-mess/

I've placed the module in `lib/core_extensions/hash/prune.rb`, and the module is declared as such:

```
module CoreExtensions
  module Hash
    module Prune
      ##
      # Removes all pairs from the Hash for which the value is nil. Destructive!
      def prune!
        self.reject! { |_, v| v.nil? }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And in order to make the monkey patch take effect, I'm calling this within the main gem file:

```
Hash.include(CoreExtensions::Hash::Prune)
```

But after building the gem and trying to require it in an irb console, I get the following error: `NameError: uninitialized constant Gem::CoreExtensions` (Gem is a placeholder name).

I made sure to include the prune.rb file in my gemspec's `files` array: `s.files = ['lib/gem.rb', 'lib/core_extensions/hash/prune.rb']`, so I'm not sure why it can't detect the file and its modules. Can anyone help me figure this out?

Thank you!

EDIT: In case it will help anyone else - I tried to `require` the module file using `require 'lib/core_extensions/hash/prune'` but received 'cannot load such file' errors. Sticking `./` in front of the path fixed it.

Comment: In the `irb` console, did you remember to `require` the file in which the module is defined?

Comment: I didn't - but now that you mention it, I did try and require the file in the main `gem.rb` file, but it failed with a `cannot load such file` error. I tweaked the statement a bit, though: `require './lib/core_extensions/hash/prune'`, and now it seems to work!

Comment: Once you loaded the file, did this work as expected? If `NameError` crops up again, double-check for typos & make sure the namespace in the console matches what's defined in the module file. Also, if you're still stuck, please copy and paste your (placeholder-ized) `irb` history.

Comment: Be sure to check that there isn't a method with that name already defined, as from time to time the Ruby core gets upgraded and a name that simple could come into conflict.

Comment: That's a great tip, @tadman, thank you.

Comment: "Sticking `./` in front of the path fixed it." – Please, for the love of god, never ever do that. That's what `require_relative` is for.